# Partitioning in a dell 660s while installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

When I chose a partition and clicked install now while ubuntu setup was running,It says 'no root file system is defined. Please correct it from the partition menu.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

During the create partion step, there is a dropdown menu for Mount Point.  Select it and choose the root directory "/".

[More detailed info can be found here](http://techhamlet.com/2010/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-10-04/)